# Where to download a zip with all Windows 7 updates up to now?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I want to format my PC and install all the Windows 7 updates up to now but I want to do it in a easy way so I want to download all the updates and run then from my disk.

Is there any simple way to download all of them and/or install them besides using Windows update?

Is there any site that gathers all the updates?

Or is it possible to patch the Windows 7 ISO with the updates (I have a licensed enterprise ISO, all legal)?

Comment: I you're in enterprise, how about a WSUS server?

Comment: I have computer without any network. I'm interesting in the answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try AutoPatcher:

http://www.autopatcher.com/whatsautopatcher/

http://www.autopatcher.com/downloads/

I've been using it for a few years.  It's a big time saver when I need to update a machine with a slow or nonexistent connection.

Comment: does it support win7? looking at the site am not sure if it has "beta" support or the support is tested and stable

Comment: Yes, it supports win7, and it's always had the beta tag, much in the way gmail carried its own perpetual beta tag.  I've been using it for years for XP, but not as long for vista and win7.  Haven't had a problem with it yet.  The only thing to note is that it is sometimes behind a patch cycle or two while things undergo testing, so if you want the absolute latest updates, you may have to hit the MS update site for the last small handful of hotfixes.  This isn't unique to this 3rd-party update tool.

Comment: Nice app. Worked fine for my Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

After some search, I've found couple ways to get updates.

First there is [CTUpdate](http://www.vulnerabilityassessment.co.uk/ctupdate.htm). You should be able to use it to get all updates and install them offline. Also, disk images can be made so you can burn updates on a disk and save them for next reinstall.

The other is [Windows Updates Downloader](http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/). You can also use it to download updates you need and them transfer them to a different computer.

I haven't used them, so I can't say which one is better.

**EDIT** It seems that none of them supports windows 7 yet.

Answer (score 2):

WSUS is able to download all existing Windows 7 updates for later offline deployment

http://www.heise.de/software/download/wsus_offline_update_ehemals_ct_offline_update/38170

Answer (score 1):

If you are not timid of the command line, give [WuInstall](http://wuinstall.com/) a try.  You can write a script for either local or remote machines.

If you are looking to slipstream your updates into an ISO insatll disk, give [vLite](http://www.vlite.net/) a try.  It was created for Vista, but I have used it personally to integrate updates into the Windows 7 install process.